# How to create an index on a child property of an array object in Firebase

Tags: firebase

In my firebase app I am storing objects in an array structure using the push() method that generates unique ids. These objects have a child property called "scheduledDate" How can I create an indexOn rule in firebase to index this field. under events each user has a node, than a child array of their events. /events/userId/arrayOfEvents

I can use orderByChild() to successfully retrieve the records by event scheduled date, but its warning me about the index.

My rules looks like this:

```
   "events":{
      ".read" : "auth != null",
      ".write" : "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": ["scheduledDate"]
    }
```

My code doing the query looks like this:

```
         this.dbEvents = new Firebase(firebaseEventsUrl);

         var q;

         q = this.dbEvents.child(userId).orderByChild("scheduledDate").limitToLast(limitToLast);

         return $firebaseArray(q);
```

My data looks like this:

```
          events:{
              user1:{
                  -K2NYCT2_uMwsTSfH58O(push generated):{
                      description: 'event 1',
                      scheduledDate: 1446730200000
                  },
                  --K2NyNh660I4k8loar-z:{
                      description: 'event 2',
                      scheduledDate: 1446730200000
                  },
              },
              user2:{

              }
          }
```

Comment: Descriptions of data or code are not the same as actual data/code. Please show a sample of your data (no screenshot please) and the code that you use to query it.

Comment: edited to show code and data structure I am working with. Again, it works, just warns me I need to index scheduledDate, and I don't know how to create that indexOn rule for a level this deep.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "events":{
      ".read" : "auth != null",
      ".write" : "auth != null",
      "$uid": {
        ".indexOn": "scheduledDate"
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "scheduledDate" at /events/simplelogin:82 to your security rules for better performance

Comment: Ah, I now see that you have a level for users in there. I'll update.

Comment: This works, thanks Frank! Can the "$uid" be named anything as a variable to represent that level?

Comment: Yup, it's just a variable name. Please read this section of the docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables

Comment: Can someone tell the best place to place the above code?

Comment: this really helped me

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your answer. I tried to add the rule to existing data but the query doesn't get any faster. My question is how long does it take for Firebase to index all the existing data?